# I want to have both public and private access to same Django REST API

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I want to have both public and private access to `/api/listings` so that I can have read-only access on my frontend on all listings publicly. I also want to read, update and delete own listings on an authenticated user which I already know how to do (commented out, I know I need to change the permission to `AllowAuthenticated`). Do I have to create a second API and how can I do that since the public API is already taking the `/api/listings` URI, thanks

```
# api.py

class ListingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny,
    ]

    serializer_class = ListingSerializer

    # This is how I can publicly access the api
    queryset = Listing.objects.all()

    # This is how I can have private access        
    # def get_queryset(self):
    #     return self.request.user.listings.all()

    # def perform_create(self, serializer):
    #    serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)

# serializers.py

class ListingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: You have the `IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly` default permission that give different permission depending on the type of reading, that might help you: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for, thanks!